# Link and expose compiled .a to Swift framework?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-frameworks

I'm trying to write a Swift framework which wraps and exposes a compiled library with a few added classes.

My project outputs the framework correctly:

```
    MyFramework
      |_ Frameworks/
         |_ compiled.a
      |
      |_ Headers/
         |_ *.h
```

But it appears that I can't access any of the classes in `compiled.a` in my application because of an undefined symbols error. If I drag and drop `compiled.a` into my project itself and add it in the "Link With Binary Files" build phase, both my framework and my application code work fine, but it takes ages to copy `compiled.a` to the bundle each time.

Is it possible to link my application against frameworks which are included in my dynamic framework, exposing the library to both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to prelink your libraries, and then add the linker flag.

You can set the "Prelink Libraries" option in "Build Settings" to read:

```
$(CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR)/path/to/libFramework.a
```

for both "Debug" and "Release" builds.

Then, you just need to add a flag to "Other Linker Flags":

```
-lFramework
```

Problem solved.